# MAMP MySQL InnoDB error

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I'm having serious trouble getting my MAMP stack sorted after upgrading to MAMP 4.0.6 - the support at MAMP says he doesn't know what the problem is and just offered a refund and that I should downgrade (but that version was crashing a lot hence the upgdrade). I rely on MAMP to do web development so wondered if anyone here can suggest some fixes?

I've pasted the MySQL error log from within MAMP but I'm a bit out of my depth with this kind of thing.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks,

Osu

```
    161206 11:46:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
    161206 11:51:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
    2016-12-06 11:51:09 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2016-12-06 11:51:09 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.33) starting as process 5472 ...
    2016-12-06 11:51:09 5472 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
    2016-12-06 11:51:09 5472 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [ERROR] InnoDB: auto-extending data file ./ibdata1 is of a different size 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [ERROR] Aborting

    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Binlog end
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
    2016-12-06 11:51:10 5472 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

    161206 11:51:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```